# Possible to save seeded PRNG in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

I'm seeding a `PRNG` in **objective-c** by writing

```
srandom(seed);
```

I'n **C#** I can save that `PRNG` away in a variable as:

```
prng = new Random(seed);
```

Is this possible in `Objective-C` as well?

The reason I want to save the `PRNG` in a variable is that a want a deterministic outcome on numbers generated immediately and later. I don't want to have the risk that another function reseeds the PRNG.

I have tried to do some research, for example reading this article that lists different libraries: http://nshipster.com/random/, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

In C, srand() and rand() are not related to objects, like in C#. srand() simply sets a global variable, and rand() reads from it. As far as I remember, Objective-C uses the original, C implementation for this library. Since there's  no objects involved, every call to the function `rand()` will always access the same PRNG seed set by `srand()`.

This doesn't mean there aren't any solutions though. First (maybe not the best solution) is writing your own PRNG as an object. Another option would be to find an object-orientated, PRNG library (I normally don't code in Objective-C so I don't have any recommendations). Finally, you could follow the standard generally used with `rand()`, and only call `srand()` once, at the beginning of your program, if that is appropriate for your application.

Answer (score 1):

The GameplayKit Foundation library provides class [GKMersenneTwisterRandomSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GKMersenneTwisterRandomSource_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKMersenneTwisterRandomSource).  You can create independently seeded multiple instances using [`initWithSeed:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GKMersenneTwisterRandomSource_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKMersenneTwisterRandomSource/initWithSeed:), and pass them around to your heart's content.

Comment: That looks perfect! Can you help me with a remaining detail? When I type (at)import GameplayKit; I get an error message: use of (at)import when modules are disabled. Is it possible to import this library with a #import statement?

Comment: Can't help you with that, I use it from Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code It may help you to save random number :

```
    unsigned int seed = 13;  /* Choose value for the seed */
    int random;

    srand(seed);             /* Set the seed                           */
    random = rand();         /* Generate a random number               */
```

Use **srand** to set the `seed`, and then use **rand()**

Hopw it will help you. Do let me know if your problem is solved or not.

Comment: I want to save away the seeded PRNG for later so that even if another function generates random numbers inbetween, it wont affect that seeded PRNG.

Comment: then take int random; as global variable and check it is nil then generate PRNG otherwise use it.